# Draft.js - add link to an image

Tags: draftjs

How to add a link to an image?
I know how to add link to text selection, but I cannot use it to select an image.

```
const selection = state.editorState.getSelection();
    if (!selection.isCollapsed()) {
        const contentState = state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
        const startKey = state.editorState.getSelection().getStartKey();
        const startOffset = state.editorState.getSelection().getStartOffset();
        const blockWithLinkAtBeginning = contentState.getBlockForKey(startKey);
        const linkKey = blockWithLinkAtBeginning.getEntityAt(startOffset);
        let url = '';
        if (linkKey) {
            const linkInstance = contentState.getEntity(linkKey);
            url = linkInstance.getData().url;
        }
        setState((prevState) => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                showUrlModal: true,
                urlValue: url,
            };
        });
    }
```

This is not usefull for an image, as the selection will be empty.

Comment: what `selection` you meaning? There is not `selection` in your code.